# elements with tabindex ignored after using skip to link

Tags: html, internet-explorer, tabs, focus, accessibility

I have a page that uses skip links to get to the navigation and content as follows:

```
<a href="#content">Skip to content</a>
```

Inside the content area I have a number of posts in two columns, and the reading order for these posts is left to right, then top to bottom. However the posts are in two column divs and the natural tab order doesn't reflect reading order - we've got around this problem using tabindex attributes.

Unfortunately, there is a problem in IE. When a user clicks the skipto link to go to #content, focus moves there correctly; however, the next tab will move focus to the *next element that has no positive tab index*. It's as if the positive tabindex elements have been removed from the tab order.

This jsfiddle demonstrates the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/grpr/qTy28/1/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a this issue recently and found a rock-solid solution for it.

Background:
An element can receive focus *only* if it has a tabindex or if it's a natively focusable element. Tabindex of 0 allows an element to be included in the natural taborder of the page. Tabindex of -1 allows for programmatic placement of focus, but not in the natural taborder. I strongly recommend against using any tabindex value above 0.

The best way I have found, though, is to use a method that temporarily focuses an element, and then cleans up the tabindex on blur. Also, it is important to maintain any original tabindex attribute that was on the element. Here's a jQuery example:

```
$.fn.access = function() {
  var target;
  target = $(this);
  target.data('original-tabindex', target.attr('tabindex') || false);
  target.attr('tabindex', '-1').on('blur focusout', function() {
    if (target.data('original-tabindex') !== false) {
      target.attr('tabindex', target.data('original-tabindex'));
    } else {
      target.removeAttr('tabindex');
    }
    target.off('blur focusout');
    return target.data('original-tabindex', false);
  }).focus();
  return target;
};
```

Here's a jsfiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/pfox/YRXq6/

Comment: Thanks for your response, patrick. I tried incorporating your script into my fiddle, but still no joy in IE. Have I done it correctly? http://jsfiddle.net/grpr/gka2J/

Comment: The 'Skip to content' and 'Skip to navigation' links are working in IE8 and IE9, but not IE7. What browsers are you trying to support? Also, get rid of ALL of the inline tabindex attributes. Seriously, don't ever use tabindex values > 0 in your code - it'll become a horrible nightmare to maintain and debug. Just rely on the natural taborder established by your code. I hope that helps :)

Comment: unfortunately the positive tabindexes have to stay - that's the problem. I already tried refactoring the code to use natural flow but it produced problems with the design (long story). So the prob is that *after* the skip to, I want focus to move to the first positive tabindex inside #content, but it goes straight to the first tabindex=0

Comment: So in the jsfiddle, after you click on *skip to content*, I want the next tab to go to the first positive tabindex; this happens in Chrome, etc., but not IE (I'm testing in IE10, but I think it's the same in earlier versions).

Comment: Man, that is an ugly problem to fix... There were a few other issues - see http://jsfiddle.net/pfox/pT6rN/ - works in IE9

Comment: I had a look in my VM - in IE9, the first tab after 'skip to content' is Tabindex=0; you don't get that? Unfortunately IE10 is our target in any case :(

Comment: Why do the tabindexes need to stay?

Comment: The design has posts arranged in columns like in google+; the original idea was to just float these into columns using CSS but keep the HTML in chronological order of post; but if a user expands a post, it either caused large gaps to appear in the layout, or caused a large refloat of posts in all columns; the preferred interaction was to just have the posts in the current column move down without affecting the other columns. So we needed to split the posts into column containers, which means source order is no longer chronological - but we want to allow users to tab through chronologically